# Issue implementing an OSX CoreMidi MidiCallback function in Lazarus/FreePascal

Tags: macos, freepascal, lazarus, coremidi

I'am struggling implementing an OSX CoreMidi MidiCallback procedure with Lazarus / FreePascal.

In the MIDIServices unit, MIDIReadProc, the callback routine, is definded:

```
MIDIReadProc = procedure( (*const*) pktlist: MIDIPacketListPtr; readProcRefCon: UnivPtr; srcConnRefCon: UnivPtr );
```

This routine is called on a separate high-priority thread owned by CoreMidi when midi events are received.

I defined a callback procedure for handling received midi events:

```
Type procedure MyMidiCallback(pktList: MIDIPacketListPtr;readProcRefCon: UnivPtr; srcConnRefCon: UnivPtrMy);     

procedure TMainForm.MyMidiCallback(pktList: MIDIPacketListPtr;readProcRefCon: UnivPtr; srcConnRefCon: UnivPtr);
begin
  //  handle midi packets
end;
```

The midi callback hook is defined in the following code at 'MidiInputPortCreate':

```
procedure TMainForm.ReceiveMidiTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  NumOfSources, NumOfDestinations: ItemCount;
  x: byte;
  MIDIDestinationPointer, MidiSourcePointer: MIDIEndpointRef;
  EndPointName: CFStringRef;
  MidiClient: MidiClientRef;
  InputPort: MidiPortRef;
  MidiCallback: MidiReadProc;
begin
  NumOfDestinations := MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations;
  NumOfSources := MIDIGetNumberOfSources;
  Memo.Lines.Add('Number of Midi Sources: ' + IntToStr(NumOfSources));
  EndPointName := nil;
  MidiClient := nil;
  InputPort := nil;
  MidiCallback := @TMainform.MyMidiCallback;

  for x := 0 to NumOfDestinations -1 do  // show destinations
    begin
      MidiDestinationPointer := MidiGetDestination(x);
      MIDIObjectGetStringProperty(MidiDestinationPointer, kMIDIPropertyName, EndPointName);
      Memo.Lines.Add('Destination ' + IntToStr(x) + ': ' + CFStrToAnsiStr(EndPointName));
    end;

  for x := 0 to NumOfSources -1 do  // show sources
    begin
      MidiSourcePointer := MIDIGetSource(x);
      MIDIObjectGetStringProperty(MidiSourcePointer, kMIDIPropertyName, EndPointName);
      Memo.Lines.Add('Source ' + IntToStr(x) + ': ' + CFStrToAnsiStr(EndPointName));
    end;

  MidiClientCreate(CFSTRP('Midi Input Client'), nil, nil, MidiClient);
  MidiInputPortCreate(MidiClient, CFSTRP('Input'), MidiCallback, nil, InputPort);  //     MidiCallback
  MIDISourcePointer := MIDIGetSource(0);  // select source(0) = midi keyboard
  MidiPortConnectSource(InputPort, MIDISourcePointer, nil);
end;
```

Compiling generates the following error message:

```
mainunit.pas(480,19) Error: Incompatible types: got "<procedure variable type of procedure(MIDIPacketListPtr,Pointer,Pointer) of object;Register>" expected "<procedure variable type of procedure(MIDIPacketListPtr,Pointer,Pointer);MWPascal>"
```

I'am stuck here now; hope someone can help.

--------------------------------- UPDATE #1 ----------------------------------

The code above was indeed a bit strange so I rewrote things:

```
procedure TMainForm.ReceiveMidiTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MidiClient: MidiClientRef;
  InputPort: MidiPortRef;
  MidiCallback: MIDIReadProc;
begin
  MidiCallback := MyMidiCallback;
  MidiClientCreate(CFSTRP('Midi Input Client'), nil, nil, MidiClient);
  MidiInputPortCreate(MidiClient, CFSTRP('Input'), MidiCallback, nil, InputPort);
  MidiPortConnectSource(InputPort, MIDIGetSource(0), nil);
end;

procedure MyMidiCallback(pktList: MIDIPacketListPtr; readProcRefCon: UnivPtr;    srcConnRefCon: UnivPtr);
begin
//  handle midi packets
end;
```

Now the code compiles without errors but as soon as i hit a key on the midi keyboard, the application crashes with the following error message:

'ERROR Project ... raised exception class 'External: Sigtrap' at address FFFFD96F'

(FFFFD96F is probably the pointer to the MidiCallback routine).

Basically, the issue I have is how to let the MidiCallback pointer in MidiInputPortCreate point correctly to my MyMidiCallback procedure where I handle midi events.

BTW, sending Midi events works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put the error declarations in the error on separate lines:

mainunit.pas(480,19) Error: Incompatible types: got "

procedure(MIDIPacketListPtr,Pointer,Pointer) of object;Register>" expected "<
procedure variable type of procedure(MIDIPacketListPtr,Pointer,Pointer);MWPascal>"

Note two crucial differences:

1) The "of object" difference in the two procedure declarations in the error means you passed a method instead of a proper procedure.

2) Besides that, calling conventions doesn't seem to match, one is mwpascal; one is Register.  Register is the default for most modes, so no calling convention modifier means register.

The "callback" part of your question is strange. You define a type as a procedure, but provide a method as implementation?

Comment: Hoi Marco, thanks for your fast response. I rewrote things and the application now compiles without errors however it crashes as soon as it receives a midi event. I did append an update of the new (simplified) code and the error message under my original question. Hope you can have a look at it.

Comment: I don't see a mwpascal. My guess would be calling convention mismatches. But I gave up Mac when they went to Intel.